# How to get wishlist data from other profile in Steam?

Tags: javascript, php, json, steam, steam-web-api

Steam has launched new wishlist: https://store.steampowered.com/wishlist/id/*customName or id*

I found the next link to get some info about user which works only if you are logged in and returns only data for current profile: https://store.steampowered.com/dynamicstore/userdata/ - wishlist is empty if I'm not logged in. I can see wishlist of other players, using the first link, where uses wishlist.js shows games.

How to get wishlist data of user (from other profile, not myself) with and without sign in?

Comment: I have the same problem :(

Answer (score 7):

You can get the data in JSON at:

[https://store.steampowered.com/wishlist/profiles/{user_id}/wishlistdata/](https://store.steampowered.com/wishlist/profiles/%7Buser_id%7D/wishlistdata/)

or

[https://store.steampowered.com/wishlist/id/{vanity_url}/wishlistdata/](https://store.steampowered.com/wishlist/id/%7Bvanity_url%7D/wishlistdata/)

Comment: This gives only a part if your list is too large

Comment: You can add `?p=1` or `?p=2` ... etc to get the next page.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to the answer of 472084: Some Steam users are shown using an ID rather than a profile number. For those users one can use the following query:

`https://store.steampowered.com/wishlist/id/{user_id}/wishlistdata/`

where `{user_id}` needs to be replaced with the actual ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using curl. Fetch the wishlist page using curl and apply `preg_match_all()` function on it to get an array of all appid of every app in a user's wishlist.

```
preg_match_all('/"appid":(\d*),/', $response, $gameids);
$gameids = $gameids[1];
print_r($gameids);die;
```

Comment: You understood the question wrong. There is no problem to get wishlist data from own profile when you are logged in. There is problem to get wishlist data of 3-rd party profile (friend, public) without and with sign in Steam.

Comment: This method works for any steam id given the url you are fetching from curl is `'https://store.steampowered.com/wishlist/profiles/'.$steam64id`

Answer (score 0):

`g_rgWishlistData` contains all the wishlist information.

browser console:
`function getAppID(item, index) {  return item.appid; }
g_rgWishlistData.map(getAppID).join(",");`